Некорректная работа проекта с libpqxx
Я пытаюсь разобраться с работой libpqxx в c++, у меня есть db в postgresql, и я пытаюсь создать соединение к ней, но по какой-то причине программа не выполняется после создания объекта соединения, то есть я вижу только сообщение "trying connect../n", работаю в vscode, на подключение самой библиотеки компилятор не жалуется, в чем может быть проблема?
#include <iostream>
#include <pqxx/pqxx>


int main() {
    // Создание строки подключения
    std::string connectionString = "dbname = Dota user = postgres password=1q2ws3edc4r hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432";
    
    try
    {
        std::cout << "trying connect../n";
        pqxx::connection connectionObject(connectionString.c_str());
        std::cout << "connection succses/n";
        pqxx::work worker(connectionObject);
        std::cout << "trans create/n";
        pqxx::result response = worker.exec("SELECT * FROM heroes_list");
        std::cout << "count of rows " << response.size() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Ошибка: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    

    return 0;
    
}


учимся пользоваться поиском: https://incpp.blogspot.com/2009/04/postgresql-libpqxx.html и, на всякий случай - советую прочесть это: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25152111/is-libpq-or-libpqxx-the-official-c-postgres-interface

А сам сервер базы данных работает? Есть в системе соответствующий процесс? И проверьте имя пользователя - в зависимости от вида установки это может быть не postgres, а имя текущего пользователя в системе.

@Ingvar, а Вы не могли бы уточнить, на что именно нужно обратить внимание в предложенной Вами ссылке? Код из вопроса вполне себе рабочий - я только что поменял значения в connection string, и изменил имя таблицы в запросе - все работает.

@isnullxbh, 1 ссылка  - это просто пример работы с библиотекой топикстартера, мало ли, вдруг поможет. А вторая... я в принципе не могу понять, зачем использовать сторонние обертки стандартной библиотеки, которая выполняет все требуемые функции, не требует сборки и поставляется как клиентская часть самого сервера. И имеет вполне нормальное документирование, в т.ч. и на русском. В качестве примера у меня есть собственный плагин доступа, базирующийся на libpq в проекте qt, предназначенный для немного более простого использования этой библиотеки. Могу поделиться.
